# Create Buttons for activity in code

Tags: android

I dont't see last button (bx), when first button array too big, for example size is 12, when size is 2 I see it. Why button doesn't     transition to second row.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
        LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);
        int size=20;
        Button[] mButtonsArray = new Button[size];

        LayoutParams Lpx= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        for (int i=0; i< size;i++) 
        {
       mButtonsArray[i]= new Button(this);
            mButtonsArray[i].setText(name);
            linLayout.addView(mButtonsArray[i], Lpx);
        }
       Button bx = new Button(this);
       bx.setText("back");
        linLayout.addView(bx, Lpx);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, your `LinearLayout linLayout` has gravity `HORIZONTAL`

```
linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

if you want to add last button in second row then you have to make a **Root LinearLayout** with `VERTICAL` then  add other buttons with parent `LinearLayout` with `HORIZONTAL` gravity and add this LinearLayout to Main Root LinearLayout with Gravity `VERTICAL`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why button doesn't transition to second row

Because that's not how a horizontal `LinearLayout` works. It positions all the children horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout views don't wrap.  So the button would be past the right edge of the screen and so not visible.

You may want to explore GridView

```
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html][1]
```